# Expo: Ejecting to a bare project is only available for SDK 34 and higher

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a Expo project that I have to eject, due to some native libraries that I must implement. But when i run `Expo eject` and chose `Bare: I'd like a bare React Native project`, the console pops up this error:

`Ejecting to a bare project is only available for SDK 34 and higher`

By searching a bit I understood that expo sdkVersion 34.0.0 is not available  yet right? If not, How can I update to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same problem as you, I found a link at Expo forum: https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-ejecting-to-a-bare-project-is-only-available-for-sdk-34-and-higher/25528 suggesting to downgrade expo-cli version with

`npm i -g expo-cli@2.21.2`

if you want to eject to plain react native.
I did so and it works, they said that SDK 34 will be released soon.